# Active Record error from crontab

Tags: ruby, activerecord, cron

When I try to run my ruby script from crontab i catch the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- active_record (LoadError) from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
```

my code is

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'active_record'
```

I am not expert, that's why I ask, why my script does not now about `ActiveRecord`? When I run it manually from folder it works well.

Comment: _manually from folder_ means ?

Comment: open terminal, cd /pathtofolder/, ruby blablabla.rb. My crontab task looks like: ruby /pathtofolder/blablabla.rb

Comment: when your script runs fine "manually" and fails when run by crond, you probably have an environment issue there. cron does not run things like .bash_rc ... so if there is anything you do locally, like sourcing RVM, that's not done for cron automagically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
I just need run in terminal
`rvm cron setup`

and then i can use

`ruby` command in cron